# Module Call in Error for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, module

When I try to call in the modules I get this error for Numpy. Why? and how to I fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoFe5.png)

Comment: Please check module exists in env not.
You can install module using !pip install numpy

Answer (score 0):

Probably not loaded 'numpy' in your system.

Try this:

```
pip install numpy
```

for python3:

```
pip3 install numpy
```